# shell script behavior across different linux distros

Tags: linux, bash, shebang

I have a general question about shell scripts and process tables across 2 different operating systems.

On a SuSE Linux system, I run a script called joe.sh. It is a simple script that does the following

---

```
echo "Hello Joe "     
read x
```

---

If I do a `ps -ef | grep [j]oe.sh -` it will find a result that will look something like this

---

```
joe      15532 24267  0 09:40 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/sh ./joe.sh
```

---

That is assuming I launch another terminal and dont hit enter on the script.

However, If I do this same thing on an oracle linux system, I get no match UNTIL I add a shebang to the script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello Joe"
read x
```

Is there some default in the environment in SuSE that would get set? I'd like to replicate that behavior on the Oracle Linux system.

Comment: What do you mean you get no match? Does the script run and terminate immediately? Does it not even execute correctly? For some reason, you are executing it with `sh` (as can be seen in your `ps` output line).  You normally want to always put in the hashbang (`#!`) anyway.

Comment: The ps -ef | grep [j]oe.sh does not return any result (on oracle). The script hangs in the process table until I input something. I set it up that way so I can pop open another xterm window and search for the process in different ways. I understand it is good practice to always include the shebang, I was just curious if somebody knew why suse would always have /bin/sh by default and oracle would not

Comment: What is the default shell on oracle, and does it support character classes (e.g. `[stuff]`?). Bash does. If the default shell on oracle doesn't, then you have your answer.

Comment: I issued the command echo $SHELL on both systems, they both come back with /bin/bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is : [interpreter-script](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#interpreter-script)

Anyway, the script should always have a shebang line. (I second John)

Answer (score 2):

Scripts should always have a shebang line unless they're intended to be `source`d. The [default shell in SuSE](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sled11/book_sle_admin/data/sec_adm_whatistheshell.html) is Bash. Add `#!/bin/bash` to the top.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your status line, the default shell being invoked is `sh`.

> joe 15532 24267 0 09:40 pts/2 00:00:00 **/bin/sh ./joe.sh**

So it is executing with `sh`.

As indicated, by default, the shell in SuSE should be Bash. However, this can be configured differently for every user. The default shell for any user (generally in UNIX-based systems) is defined in the `/etc/passwd` file.

Each line of that file is a user, and the fields are separated by `:` symbols. The 7th field is the default user shell (the shell to execute when the user logs in).

A more detailed explanation can be found at: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/